# Tools/API's/Frameworks for Java Web-Based workflow

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, soa, business-process-management

I'm working on a project that requires a Web-based workflow application. We're now evaluating software stacks for the project, and most of my colleagues agree in the use of IBM SOA-BPM products as base software (that includes Process Server and Websphere Business Modeler). The client has the license of almost all of the tools, so that approach make sense.

However, I'm curious if there is any other software-stack for that kind of application. In a quick Google search I found this:

- [Spring Workflow](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-workflow), sounds nice but it's in Incubation phase
- Using an Open-Source workflow engine like [Imixs](http://www.imixs.org/), but having Process Server already that doesn't make any sense
- [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2005/jw-0411-spring.html?page=1) suggest a pure Spring-Beans based solution, but it feels a little like reinventing the wheel

Any suggestion, or I should go with the full-IBM solution?

**Edit:**

Another question, is BPM the only way for Workflow applications, or there are other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) is an embeddable workflow engine that we have been using for a while. It has a very good active community and a very good book "Activiti in Action". It is light weight and based on the BPMN open standard. Check my earlier question [Which workflow engine to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940173/which-workflow-engine-to-choose)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look. Have try or discovered somthing non-BPM based?

Comment: @CarlosGavidia - nope haven't came across anything other than web flow

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when mixing up BPM with Workflow.
[Imixs Workflow](http://www.imixs.org) is a java based workflow framework for building business applications. In different to IBM SOA-BPM or Activiti, the focus of this framework is to support users working on tasks provided by an application.

This means Imixs Workflow allows you to manage human based workflow tasks. For example you can secure a process instance to different actors. You can define email notifications. Or you can design a workflow history which shows up what users have done so far in a particular process instance. The workflow engine informs actors about new tasks and provides them with task lists. Imixs Workflow helps users to complete their tasks inside a business application.

The Imixs Workflow framework is useful when your project focuses on human based workflow. It is not so much a framework to automate business processes.