# Process Engines for BPMN 2.0

Tags: workflow, jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn, activiti

I'm doing a comparison among all existing BPMN 2.0 Process Engines e.g. Activiti, jBPM etc.
I've prepared a list of 4 process engines which executes BPMN 2.0 given below;

Popular BPMN 2.0 compliant open-source engines:

```
Activiti: http://www.activiti.org/
jBPM: http://www.jboss.org/jbpm
Bonita: http://www.bonitasoft.com/
```

A commercial engine:

```
ActiveVOS: http://www.activevos.com/products
```

I would appreciate your help if you enhance my research by adding any existing Process Engines (for BPMN 2.0) in the above list along with the quick comparison among all.

I would prefer a very short comparison listing only important features (distinguishing features like what is possible for one and not for others, licensing, dependencies with other products like tomcat & JBoss and operating systems etc)

P.S: I've found much on Activiti vs jBPM but still your answers will be a favor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which workflow engine to choose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940173/which-workflow-engine-to-choose)

Comment: I had gone through this link before but I'm more interested in knowing more existing engines like I found ActiveVOS and Camunda fox (in an answer by Rafael within the current session).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot offer you a full-fledged comparison but I can give you some pointers that might help you in your evaluation:

1. An "[Activiti in Action](http://www.manning.com/rademakers2/)" book has just been published (July
   2012) and in it you will have a section reviewing other BPMN process
   engines (Section 1.2.3 - Knowing the competitors).
2. For Activiti, there also exists since recently, a commercially-supported version called [camunda fox BPM Platform](http://www.camunda.com/fox/). They also provide a comparison with the added-value they provide [here](http://www.camunda.com/fox/enterprise/open-source-vs-enterprise/).

Comment: Thank You very much. That was quite helpful. I actually spent the whole day and found lot of features but still some ambiguities are there regarding the possibilities of Application Servers Integration.

Answer (score 4):

I am disappointed with Activiti.  It should be called Spring BPM because it doesn't work well without it. If you don't mind using Spring, then Activiti might be a better fit.  If you are using JEE/CDI, then JBPM is a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

I did such a research, too. Here are the key-points which were relevant for our concrete use case:

1. Bonita:

Bonita has a zero-coding approach which means that they provide an easy to use IDE to build your processes without the need for coding. To achieve that, Bonita has the concept of connectors. For example, if you want to consume a web service, they provide you with a graphical wizzard. The downside is that you have to write the plain XML SOAP-envelope manually and copy it in a graphical textbox. The problem with this approach is that you only can realize use cases which are intended by Bonita. If you want to integrate a system which Bonita did not developed a connector for, you have to code such a connector on your own which is very painful. For example, Bonita offers a SOAP connector for consuming SOAP web services. This connector only works with SOAP 1.2, but not for SOAP 1.1 (http://community.bonitasoft.com/answers/consume-soap-11-webservices-bonita-secure-web-service-connector). If you have a legacy application with SOAP 1.1, you cannot integrate this system easily in your process. The same is true for databases. There are only a few database connectors for dedicated database versions. If you have a version not matching to a connector, you have to code this on your own.

In addition, Bonita has no support for LDAP or Active Directory Sync in the free community edition which is quite a showstopper for a production environment. Another thing to consider is that Bonita is licensed under the GPL / LGPL license which could cause problems when you want to integrate Bonita in another enterprise application. In addition, the community support is very weak. There are several posts which are more than 2 years old and those posts are still not answered.

Another important thing is Business-IT-Alignment. Modelling processes is a collaborative discipline in which IT AND the business analysts are involed. That is why you need adequate tools for both user groups (e.g. an Eclipse Plugin for the developers and an easy to use web modeler for the business people). Bonita only offers Bonita Studio, which needs to be installed on your machine. This IDE is quite technical and not suitable for business users. Therefore, it is very hard to realize Business-IT-Alignment with Bonita.

Bonita is a BPM tool for very trivial and easy processes. Because of the zero-coding approach, the lerning curve is very low and you can start modelling very fast. You need less programming skills and you are able to realize your processes without the need of coding. But as soon as your processes become very complex, Bonita might not be the best solution because of the lack of flexibility. You only can realize use cases which are intended by Bonita.

jBPM:

jBPM is a very powerful Open Source BPM Engine which has a lot of features. The web modeler even supports prefabricated models of some van der Aalst workflow patterns (workflowpatterns.com). Business-IT-Alignment is realizable because jBPM offers an Eclipse integration as well as a web-based modeler. A bit tricky is that you only can define forms in the web modeler, but not in the Eclipse Plugin, as far as I know. To sum up, jBPM is a good candidate for using in a company. Our showstopper was the scalability. jBPM is based on the Rules-Engine Drools. This leads to the fact that whole process instances are persisted as BLOBS in the database. This is a critial showstopper when you consider searching and scalability.

In addition, the learning curve is very high because of the complexity. jBPM does not offer a Service Task like the BPMN-Standard suggests In contrast, you have to define your own Java Service tasks and you have to register them manually in the engine, which results in quite low level programming.

Activiti:

In the end, we went with Activiti because this is a very easy to use framework-based engine. It offers an Eclipse Plugin as well as a modern AngularJS Web-Modeler. In this way, you can realize Business-IT-Alignment. The REST-API is secured by Spring Security which means that you can extend the Engine very easily with Single Sign-on features. Because of the Apache License 2.0, there is no copyleft which means you are completely free in terms of usage and extensibility which is very important in a productive environment.

In addition, the BPMN-coverage is very good. Not all BPMN-elements are realized, but I do not know any engine which does that.

The Activiti Explorer is a demo frontend which demonstrates the usage of the Activiti APIs. Since this frontend is based on VAADIN, it can be extended very easily. The community is very active which means that you can get help very fast if you have any problems.

Activiti offers good integration points for external form-technologies which is very important for a productive usage. The form-technologies of all candidates are very restrictive. Therefore, it makes sense to use a standard form-technology like XForms in combination with the Engine. Even such more complex things are realizable via the formKey-Attribute.

Activiti does not follow the zero-coding approach which means that you will need a bit of coding if you want to orchestrate services. But even the communication with SOAP services can be achieved by using a Java Service Task and Apache CXF. The coding effort is low.

I hope that my key points can help by taking a decision. To be clear, this is no advertisment for Activiti. The right product choice depends on the concrete use cases. I only want to point out the most important points in our project.

Best regards Ben

Comment: Based on your excellent answer I started evaluating Activity as well.
 
The community edition works well even if I found several bugs just after 2 days of programming. But their GUI is based on Vaadin which is not suitable for us. And the explorer is not designed to be used in production. 

The commercial version is based on AngularJS and has a good GUI designer. But it's very expensive 48 000 Euro/year. Which GUI do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In Activiti 6, the Activiti Explorer will be replaced by an Angular JS Frontend (even in the Open Source Verison): http://activiti.org/slides2015paris/activiti6_ui.pdf. For Activiti 5.17, we use a custom Tasklist with XForms as form rendering technology. Maybe, you want to look into the code of Activiti 6 on github to get an impression of the new features: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/activiti6

Answer (score 2):

Nommy, you should take a look at Roubroo - a process engine built to natively support BPMN 2.0. It does not have the legacy of an older process engine being retrofitted to support the new standard. It support BPMN 2.0 execution semantics including the IOR gateway, which I think is the key to way business processes are defined in a networked graph. jBPM and Activiti are based on the underlying PVM, which has great support for some workflow patterns but not for others. Take a look at this research paper : http://eprints.qut.edu.au/14320/1/14320.pdf
and http://www.workflowpatterns.com/evaluations/opensource/

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion currently Camunda BPM Platform the leader in the open source field.
And you mentioned Open Source?
So try camunda  if you like:
- Clean BPMN focused engine (Shared, Embedable or "remote")
- Clean and working REST API
- Out of the box Platform with basic administration tools, and development ready API's
- Biggest open-source community (my persnoal oppinion)
- Best of Breed approach in the java eco-system.
- If you like Java.
- If you want to that your Processes get accepted by your IT crowd.
http://www.camunda.com/fox/product/details/

Answer (score 0):

jBPM5 is agnostic to the environment, it doesn't depend on JBoss, you can run it in every Application Server, Servlet Container or a SE environment. jBPM5 is licensed with the Apache Software License V2 which I believe that is a really good idea. 
You can of course find more information in the official page.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but as far as I know, Activiti also doesn't depend on tomcat only. Rather all 4 above mentioned engines can be deployed to JBoss, tomcat, IBM WebSphere and Oracle WebLogic etc.

Comment: I read the following on activiti.org/userguide/#demo.setup
"Note that the Activiti demo setup is a way of showing the capabilities and functionality of Activiti as easy and as fast as possible. This does however, not mean that it is the only way of using Activiti. As Activiti is 'just a jar', it can be embedded in any Java environment: with swing or on a Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere, etc. Or you could very well choose to run Activiti as a typical, standalone BPM server. If it is possible in Java, it is possible with Activiti!"

Comment: The same is true for jBPM5, just jars

Answer (score 0):

Regarding jBPM: 
jBPM is an open-source workflow engine written in Java that can execute business processes described in BPMN 2.0 (or its own process definition language jPDL in earlier versions). It is released under the ASL (or LGPL in earlier versions) by the JBoss company
It includes,

- Strong and powerful integration with business rules and event processing.
- Process collaboration, monitoring and management through the Guvnor repository and the management consoles.
- Human interaction using an independent WS-HT human task service.

In essence jBPM takes graphical process descriptions as input. A process is composed of tasks that are connected with sequence flows. Processes represent an execution flow. The graphical diagram (flow chart) of a process is used as the basis for the communication between non-technical users and developers.

Answer (score 0):

Take also a look at [Imixs-Workflow](http://www.imixs.org) which is a human-centric workflow engine. Unlike the usual engines, Imixs workflow is characterised by strong support for user-centric.

Human-centric business process management means supporting human skills, activities and collaboration in a task-oriented manner. With such a Workflow engine you can protect and securely distribute business data within an event-driven BPM architecture based on the BPMN 2.0 standard.

The Imixs-Workflow engine is open source and can be integrated in Jakarta EE oder deployed out of the box with a [Microservice](https://www.imixs.org/sub_microservice.html) running in a Docker container

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Zeebe.io](https://zeebe.io) - a modern, cloud-native workflow engine with first-class Node.js support.