# Guidelines for implementing a rule engine

Tags: rule, rule-engine

What could be the reasons to implement your own rule engine instead of using an existing commercial/open source one? Any specific guidelines for implementing rule engines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this post for argument for implementing your own:

[Rules Engine - pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250403/rules-engine-pros-and-cons)

mainly the problem centers around the anemic data model anti-pattern. as described here:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

How you should implement depends very much on the requirements but generally important points to consider when designing your own include.

- Make the ability to add rules dynamic. So you don't have to shut down the system to edit rules.
- Match the rules syntax to the appropriate user level, don't expect a secretary to be writing SQL.
- Take advantage of your domain knowledge to implement your domain models which you will run your rules against.
- Drools is a good bit of software, try to learn lessons from how that was implemented.
- Try to modularize your rules engine so it functions independent of any business process tools you might be using